# Strange output using if/else in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I have the following code:

```
char command;
cin >> command;
if ( command == 'P' ) {
    do_something();
}
if ( command == 'Q' ) {
    cout << "Exit\n";
    exit(0);
}
else {
    cout << "command= " command << endl; //use for debugging
    cout << "Non-valid input\n";
    exit(1);
}
cout << "exit at completion\n";
exit(0);
}
```

When I use input of `P`, my output after `do_something()` finishes is:

```
"output from do_something() function"
command= P
Non-valid input
```

My question is why do I still get the `Non-valid input` after `do_something()` is called in the first if statement? AKA why does the else still run when `do_something()` finishes?

Comment: Is the else statement after the first if missing, or that's the desired code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You left out the `else` before the second `if`, which means that if `command != 'Q'` (which is true for `P`), the `exit` block will be executed.

You probably meant to do

```
if ( command == 'P' ) {
    do_something();
}
else if ( command == 'Q' ) { // Note the 'else'
    cout << "Exit\n";
    exit(0);
}
else {
    cout << "command= " command << endl; //use for debugging
    cout << "Non-valid input\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

That way, when the command is `P`, `do_something` will be called and all the rest will be skipped.

Comment: Did we just answer at the **exact** same time?:D

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I think so haha :)

Comment: Removed mine, you typed more :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore & Seth Carnegie How the f*** you guys manage to answer that fast all the time. Just sitting and lurking or what? ;o) ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` is associated with **second** `if` not the first one. So after finishing first `if` it enters the `else` part of second if. Thats why you are getting this. You should use this

```
char command;
cin >> command;
if ( command == 'P' ) {
    do_something();
}
else if ( command == 'Q' ) {
    cout << "Exit\n";
    exit(0);
}
else {
    cout << "command= " command << endl; //use for debugging
    cout << "Non-valid input\n";
    exit(1);
}
cout << "exit at completion\n";
exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two `if` statements are independent of each other...
The else is with the second `if` condition. So it never goes into the second `if` condition and always into its `else` part.
The first `if` condition has no `else` part.